# The program asks for numbers continuously without user control, failing to implement the "yes/no" check for more inputs, resulting in an infinite loop

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop

I have started java a while ago and for practice I tried to code a program which takes numbers as inputs in a loop and when the user tells the program to stop, it will display sum of all even and sum of all odd numbers. However it skipped the part where the program asks for user wether they would like to add more numbers or stop, it just kept repeating the input number again and again.

```
import java.util.*;
public class EvenOdd_sum{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum1=0;
        int sum2=0;
        boolean ch=true;
        while(ch){
            System.out.println("Enter the number:");
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            if(n%2==0){
                sum1+=n;
            }
            else{
                sum2+=n;
            }
            System.out.println("Enter yes or no for more inputs:");
            String s = sc.nextLine(); 

            if (s == "no"){
                ch=false;
            }else if(s == "yes"){
                ch=true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of even numbers="+sum1);
        System.out.println("Sum of odd numbers="+sum2);
    }
```

I tried to rewrite the code but got no avail as problem persisted, even asked bard for help but even they gave the wrong answer.

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  Using a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes and observe its exact runtime values and behaviors.  When doing so, you can narrow down the problem to the first specific operation which produces an unexpected result, making note of the exact values used in that operation and its result.

Comment: Make your variable names self-documenting. `sum1` tells us nothing. Something like `sumOfEvens` tells us all we need to know. `keepEntering = ("yes".equals(userEntry));`

Comment: Easier to ask your users for y/n of course

Comment: @g00se  Even easier to ask for `y` and default to `n`.  Or vise versa.